# How to pass an array arg to a Groovy JAR from command line?

Tags: java, groovy, jar, command-line-arguments, system-properties

My Groovy app has the following code:

```
def doSomething() {
    def props = [
        "fizz",
        "buzz"
    ]

    // Do something with 'props'...
}
```

**Please note** that `props` could grow quite long (10+ elements) over time.

I now want to read `props` from a switch at the command line (so, as System properties). So I'd like my code to be *something* like this:

```
def doSomething() {
    def props = System.getProperty("props")

    // Do something with 'props'...
}
```

So I could then run the app via:

```
java -Dprops=??? -jar myapp.jar
```

But now sure how to specify an array of Strings from the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: java -Dprops="hi"-jar myapp.jar but i don't know about groovy

Comment: Thanks @madhawapriyashantha but I don't think you read my question at all. `props` is an **array**. "hi" is just a single string...

Comment: ok then you can pass like that 
java -DpProp1=sp1 -DpysProp2=sp2 -jar myapp.jar.but u have to catch one by one from your code and create array from series of srings.

Comment: i didn't .upvote from me

Comment: I do not understand why this was down voted. This is absolutely a valid question with valid answers.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be built-in support for this, so I ended up going with:

```
System.getProperty("props").split(";")
```

Then from the command-line:

```
java -Dprops="fizz;buzz;etc" -jar myapp.jar
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro, but patience! I can't mark my own answer as correct for 24 hrs ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As you said, there is no built in support but you can try this:

```
 ArrayList props = System.getProperty("props").replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("]","").split(",")
```

and call it with:

```
java -Dprops="['fizz','buzz']" -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a property file and using ConfigSlurper
e.g. something like

```
File configFile = new File(configDir, 'config.groovy')
ConfigObject config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(configFile.toURI().toURL())
def props = config.props
```

where config.groovy looks like

```
props = ["fizz","buzz","etc"]
```

Or using CliBuilder to pass command line args

e.g. something like

```
CliBuilder cli = new CliBuilder(usage: "blah:")
cli.p(argName: 'prop', longOpt: 'prop', args: Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES, required: true, valueSeparator: ',', '')
def options = cli.parse(args)
def props = options.ps // ps gives you all the -p args
```

then

```
java -jar myapp.jar -p fizz,buzz,etc
or alternate allowed syntax
java -jar myapp.jar -p fizz -p buzz -p etc
```